# Pandas df.to_dict prints the name of column in values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
                                        \def
\orth                                                                    
dog                                      one who borks
cat                                      one who meows
...
```

I want to turn this into a dictionary of the following sort:

```
dict = {'dog': {'one', 'who', 'borks'}, 'cat': {'one', 'who', 'meows'}}
```

I tried the following code:

```
df_to_dictionary = df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

but this produces the following dictionary:

```
{'dog': {'\\def': 'One who borks'}, 'cat': {'\\def': 'one who meows'}}
```

Obviously the above command won't split the value, but I don't get why it's printing the column name (`\def`) in every value.

Comment: _why it's printing the column name (\def) in every value_ Because it's creating a dictionary of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
dct = df['\def'].str.split().agg(set).to_dict()

Out[291]: {'dog': {'borks', 'one', 'who'}, 'cat': {'meows', 'one', 'who'}}
```

Comment: This worked great. I am guessing that the `.agg(set)` is what gets rid of the column name in every value set?

Comment: @BOBjwjwj3j3j: no, `agg(set)` to convert list of strings to set of strings. Simply use `Series.to_dict` is the reason we are able to get rid of the columns name :). We need to agg because `str.split` splits string to list of string while we want set of strings. `df['\def'].str.split().agg(set)` returns series, so we chain `to_dict` to it that is we call `Series.to_dict`